# Problems with masonry image loading

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-masonry

I'm having a bit of a problem on one of my pages which is grabbing a lot of images from the server, dumping them on screen, and using masonry to lay them all out.

All the images load, but it seems like masonry is being called way before the images have loaded as towards the bottom, all the images load in a mess. I have attached a few screenshots to show you. Note that this happens on other pages too.

[image]
[image]

And some of the important code I am using.

```
<script>
$.each($('.img-grid-container img'), function (index, obj) {
    $(this).css({
        'width' : (50 + Math.round((Math.random()) * 330))
    });
});
</script>

<script>
var $container = $('.img-grid-container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $('#grid-section').fadeIn("normal");
    $('#loader-container').hide();
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.attachment-full',
  columnWidth: 30
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help is always appreciated.

-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I think it looks pretty cool as it, just make them draggables and your done...] ANYHOW:

Your masonry code looks fine to me [I have something almost identical working for me] but:

- Is all your JQuery inside a document ready?
- What happens if you call masonry first then fade your #grid-section in?
- I wonder if your container selector is the problem. If you have multiple instances of that class on your page then I don't know if imagesLoaded will trigger after the first, or last of those instances loads..?

[if it helps you can use .masonry('reload') to sort your bricks at any time]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't have the masonry wrapped in a document ready, so will try that first (I felt the imagesLoaded should've fixed that).